# CSS and .tpl classes; text align center

Tags: html, css

Your help would be immensely appreciated and thank you in advance to the audience.

I am having a small problem of CSS and .tpl files. I am currently building a site for a client using weebly cms. Which is great. However they are now using 'less' instead of normal css. This means they have partials and variables included now. Which I am unfamiliar with. I simply want to align some text to 'center' which is always a straight forward process in traditional CSS. In this case. the div class for the text in question lies within the .tpl file in 'partials' There is no class associated with the text in the normal CSS file.

I'd like to know if I could add the class within the normal CSS from the .tpl file. I have tried using the same class name from the .tpl within CSS using id tags and class tags i.e # and .

However with no success. Im sure it is relatively straight forward but I cannot get my little head around it.

Any help would be superb, Happy new year all!

Thank you

This is the .tpl code in question, as you can see the class names are simple.

wsite-com-product-price
wsite-com-price
wsite-come-catergory-product-price

```
<div class="wsite-com-product-price {{price_class}}">
    <div class="wsite-com-price {{!
        }}{{^is_featured}}wsite-com-category-product-price{{/is_featured}} {{!
        }}{{#is_featured}}wsite-com-category-product-featured-price{{/is_featured}}">
        {{{price_html}}}
    </div>
```

The CSS relating is this: the first line is my attempt at making this work:

```
.wsite-com-price .wsite-com-product-price .wsite-com-category-product-price {
 text-align: center;
}
```

I simply would just like to align the price to center:

[image: Text align center]

The following is the HTML from view source on the page, (how i found the class names, but they are in .tpl file not the css!)

```
<div class="wsite-com-category-product-name wsite-com-link-text">
  Merola Choker 1
</div>
</a>

<div class="wsite-com-product-price ">
  <div class="wsite-com-price wsite-com-category-product-price ">
    &pound;125.00 - &pound;165.00
  </div>
  <div class="wsite-com-sale-price wsite-com-category-product-price ">
    &pound;125.00 - &pound;165.00
  </div>
</div>

</div>  
</div>
<div class="wsite-com-category-product wsite-com-column " data-id="5">
  <div class="wsite-com-category-product-wrap ">
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ANYONE INTERESTED!

CORRECT ANSWERS SCREENSHOTS BELOW>>> THANKS!!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: putting spaces between classes means that each next class is a descendent of the previous.  if you remove the spaces it means the element must have all classes (which is what I think you are after)

Comment: `.wsite-com-price .wsite-com-product-price` – that would select an element with the class `wsite-com-product-price` that is inside an element with the class `wsite-com-price`. In your HTML, it is the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
.wsite-com-category-product-price {text-align: center;}
```

As combinations of other classes might not always work.

Or:

```
.wsite-com-price, .wsite-com-product-price, .wsite-com-category-product-price  {text-align: center}
```

To cover all price related classes.

Comment: Dear Alaksander, Deadfishli and Giker, Thankyou so much for all your help. All your answers were correct. I implemented your suggestions and they worked! Text is now aligned to center! I used the code supplied by you all and voila. They are now centered. I spent 2 hours on this yesterday! You experts did it within 6 minutes! Thankyou so so much! I have taken screenshots to show you but not sure how to upload in comments, I will add them to my question so you can see the satisfaction of your answers! amazing! thanks again! Kinds regards. Tan

Comment: I Have added your  fixes in the screenshotswork in the question section itself!

Comment: @Limtu please upvote and accept one of the answers if they helped you

Answer (score 1):

```
.wsite-com-price .wsite-com-product-price .wsite-com-category-product-price {
text-align: center;

}
```

Here  **.wsite-com-price** is expected to be parent class, which is not there in your tpl. (or did i missout).

```
.wsite-com-product-price, .wsite-com-category-product-price {
text-align: center;
}
```

Try this if, this works,  they you missed the parent class.